# Prove $\sin{x}+\sin{y} = 2\sin{x+y \over 2}\cos{x-y \over 2}$ using the Cauchy product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I want to use the Cauchy product to prove
$$\sin{x}+\sin{y} = 2\sin{x+y \over 2}\cos{x-y \over 2}$$
My idea is to use the Taylor series expansions of the sine and cosine and transform the RHS using the formula for the Cauchy product. Doing this, I pretty quickly get stuck on rewriting the Cauchy product. Do you have any hints?

This is how far I am able to get using the Cauchy product:
$$\sin {x+y \over 2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n (x+y)^{2n+1} \over (2n+1)!}$$
$$\cos {x-y \over 2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n (x-y)^{2n} \over (2n)!}$$
$$c_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^i (x+y)^{2i+1} \over (2i+1)!}{(-1)^{n-i} (x-y)^{2(n-i)} \over (2(n-i))!}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{(-1)^n(x+y)^{2i+1}(x-y)^{2(n-i)}\over (2i+1)!(2(n-i))!}$$

Comment: Why prove this in the most difficult and inelegant way ? It follows directly from the sum formula for trigonometric functions.

Comment: use the Taylor expansion of the sine and cosine product on the right hand side, and then use cauchy product to combine the sums into one.

Comment: Look at $(a+b)^{2n+1} + (a-b)^{2n+1}$.

Comment: $\sin x+\sin y=\sin(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2})+\sin(\frac{x+y}{2}-\frac{x-y}{2})$